# numpy random matrix with bounds along each axis

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

with

a = numpy.random.randomint(lo,hi,(m,n))

I can create a numpy matrix of size m, populated with random values between 'hi' and 'lo'.

Is there a way to create a numpy matrix with say random values such that

along column 1 I have numbers btween 'hi1', 'lo1' and

along column 2 I have numbers between 'hi2' and 'lo2' etc.

i.e. each column will have its own hi,low.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an array for lo & hi (depending on numpy version -- check with `numpy.version.version`). See the documentation: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html.

So for the new version of numpy you could write something like this:

```
low = [0,1,2,3]
high = [4,5,6,7]
a = numpy.random.randint(low, high, size=(3,4))
```

And for an older version of numpy this could work:

```
low = [0,1,2,3]
high = [4,5,6,7]
a = numpy.concatenate([numpy.random.randint(low[idx], high[idx], size=(3,1)) for idx in range(4)], axis=1)
```